# Can not install app in android version 12?

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console, android-12

I've installed Android 12 this morning and am getting an error when trying to install the Look Prior app. Checking in to see if anyone saw similar error messages and have any probable fixes. Thanks for the help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not [a programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and would be more appropriate for [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updated your targetLevelSdk to 31 and complieSdk to 31 in project .
So you facing this issues because your application which have on playStore is not targetting Android 12.